# explicit type annotation in Rust with private type

Tags: rust, tor, type-annotation

I want to find out the type of a variable in Rust:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use arti_client::{TorClient, TorClientConfig};
extern crate tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let config = TorClientConfig::default();
    let tor_client = TorClient::create_bootstrapped(config).await?;

    // What is the type of `tor_client`?

    Ok(())
}
```

In order to find out the type of the variable `tor_client`, I used `std::any::type_name`:

```rust
use std::any::type_name;
fn type_of<T>(_: T) -> &'static str {
    type_name::<T>()
}

[...]

println!("{}", type_of(tor_client));
```

The type printed to stdout is `arti_client::client::TorClient<tor_rtcompat::PreferredRuntime>`.

I naively assumed that I can now declare the variable with that explicit type annotation:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use arti_client::{TorClient, TorClientConfig};
extern crate tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let config = TorClientConfig::default();
    let tor_client: arti_client::client::TorClient<tor_rtcompat::PreferredRuntime> =
        TorClient::create_bootstrapped(config).await?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

However, the compiler absolutely does not like that:

```
error[E0603]: module `client` is private
   --> src/main.rs:52:34
    |
52  |     let tor_client: arti_client::client::TorClient<tor_rtcompat::PreferredRuntime> =
    |                                  ^^^^^^ private module
    |
note: the module `client` is defined here
   --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/arti-client-0.3.0/src/lib.rs:220:1
    |
220 | mod client;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^


error: aborting due to previous error
```

What do I do wrong? I assume that the `arti_client::client` module is private for a reason...

Background on why I want to find out the type and use explicit type annotation: I want to pass a reference to that variable to a custom function. As far as I understand it, I can not / should not declare a function parameter without knowing the type.

Comment: Note you can deliberately mark the variable type as `()` and then the compiler will tell you the real type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `client` module is private, but this doesn't mean that you can't access the struct.

To see the exact type as it is intended to be used, you can check the [documentation](https://docs.rs/arti-client/latest/arti_client/struct.TorClient.html#method.create_bootstrapped) for the method in question; the signature of the method is this:

```
pub async fn create_bootstrapped(config: TorClientConfig) -> Result<Self>
```

where `Self` is an alias for `arti_client::TorClient<tor_rtcompat::PreferredRuntime>`.

As you can see, this type is indeed the `TorClient`, as the `type_name` told you, but it is scoped directly in the `arti_client` crate root - not in the `client` module. To understand this difference, let's check the [source](https://docs.rs/arti-client/latest/src/arti_client/lib.rs.html#220-228):

```
mod client;
// skipped
pub use client::{BootstrapBehavior, DormantMode, StreamPrefs, TorClient};
```

So:

- module `client` is indeed private;
- `struct TorClient` is defined there, and that's what `type_name` shows;
- but it is reexported from the crate root, so you can use it without accessing private module.